# Get the stacktrace from an exception object in another function

Tags: android, exception, stack-trace

I am working on android library where I am keeping track of crashes within my apps.

I have a test app which I make it thrown an exception, an I am then passing this exception to my library. What I need to do is get the stacktrace for this exception.

Below is how I am calling the function.

```
catch (NullPointerException ex)
        {
            CrashReporter.ReportCrash(ex);
        }
```

The function where I am getting the exception details, where I also need the stacktrace.

```
public static void ReportCrash(Object exceptionObject)
    {
        String exceptionType = exceptionObject.getClass().getName();
        Log.d("Exception Type", exceptionType);
        Log.d("Device Name", android.os.Build.MODEL);
        Log.d("Device Brand", android.os.Build.BRAND);
        Log.d("Android API Level", String.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT));
        Log.d("Android Name", CommonTasks.convertApiLevelToAndroidName(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT));
        Log.d("Screen Resolution", CritiMon.appContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels + " x " + CritiMon.appContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
        Log.d("Exception", exceptionObject.toString());

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (StackTraceElement element : exceptionObject.getStackTrace()) {
    Log.d("Exception", element.toString());
}
```

And either change `exceptionObject` to type `Exception`, or cast it for `getStackTrace()`.